# Tab Bar Controller doesn't update frames when hidden

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I've been working on an application for about 8 months now, and have never had a problem with this until today. When I open up a specific page in my application, I need to hide the tab bar. However, ever since I switched to Xcode 9 - Beta, i've been having a problem that whenever the tab bar becomes hidden, it doesn't update the view to stretch to the edge. It just leaves a black space on the bottom of the screen.

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

// This fixed the problem, but I never had to do this before. What else can be the cause of this problem
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = cgRect.zero
```

This is what the page looks like when I hide the tab bar:

[image]

These are the attributes of my Tab Bar Controller:
[image: Tab Bar Controller Attributes]

Comment: I added the tab bar controller through storyboards

Comment: What do you need to see, would it help if I showed you the attributes of my Tab Bar Controller? I'll upload a pic of that

Comment: I am using multiple storyboards, and the tab bar isn't the initial view controller

Comment: Fine, but then you must do something to fetch the tab bar controller and get it into the interface. What do you do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165081/discussion-between-vapp-and-matt).